# Handling equals sign and question mark in URL

Tags: regex

I am new to regex and am trying to extract from a database a list of URLs that match xyz.asp? followed by any eight digit RequestID numbers. I can't figure out what is wrong with my expression: /abcd/.*.asp\?\w+=.*?[0-9]*?

Example:

> http://example.com/abcd/xyz.asp?RequestID=20100401

Do I have it wrong with 1) not starting/ending with ^$ 2) escaping the dot 3) escaping the question mark 4) matching the equals sign 5) or something else?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand the first part ( /abcd/..asp )

Why don't you just use

```
(.*)\.asp\?\w+=.?[0-9]*
```

Answer (score 1):

If *all* the urls are in that format, you could just split the string at the "=" and get the 2nd returned item.